# Micronaut, declarative Http-Client, JSON serialization wraps HTTP Post object

Tags: java, json-deserialization, micronaut

i am using micronaut to write a service communicating with another service.

I am using declarative http-client.

While sending a request object with declarative `http-client`, while serialization, something wraps the object equal to the parameter name of the

I have an Object which shall be serialized

```
@Getter // lombok
@Setter
@Serdeable
public class RequestObject {
private Long id;
}
```

The `http-client` looks like the following, using [documentation](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-http-client-maven-java.html). (Jackson is excluded, only Micronaut SerDes is use)

```
@Client(id = "thirdservice")
@Header(name = ACCEPT, value = "application/vnd.github.v3+json, application/json")
public interface RemotServiceClient extends RemotServiceOperations {

@Post("/api/endpoint")
ObjectResponse createPostRequest(RequestObject requestObject); // this parameter name is used to wrap
```

So when i expect the client to serialize `RequestObject` i would assume the serialization looks like:

```
{ "id": "123"}
```

instead it is serializing

```
{ "requestObject" : { "id": "123"}}
```

I was reading about `@JsonRootName` which is disabled by default. Also when i set `@JsonRootName("differentValue)` there is not effect.

I guess it is some kind of settings within the `http-client`, which i cannot find out for now.
Any tips appreciated.

Also i would like to avoid serializing manually the json from the object, like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765570/suppress-wrapper-object-when-serializing-java-object-into-json-using-jackson).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotate the method parameter by `io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body` annotation:

```java
@Post("/api/endpoint")
ObjectResponse createPostRequest(
    @Body RequestObject requestObject
);
```

Then it will be serialized as you expected:

```json
{ "id": "123"}
```

Documentation https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientParameters

---

The same behavior is when you write a server (controller).

Where the variable resolution is moreover better explained in the documentation: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#_variable_resolution